# ActiveRecord Query where field doesn't exist on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a bit of a complex query I'm trying to write.

I want to find all `Order`s that have a negative balance, but balance isn't a field on `Order` it's a method in the `Order` class that calls three other methods that call other methods, and by the end, about 5 classes are called, making doing this in SQL or writing a long AR query very difficult.

Is there a way to get the result without pulling the records and looping over them, and without reimplementing each method that builds the order balance?

For reference, I'm doing it like this right now:

```
    negative_balances = []
    Order.find_each {|o| negative_balances << o if o.balance > 0}
    @negative_balances = negative_balances.group_by {|o| o.created_at.to_date}
```

and balance looks like this:

```
class Order < AR::Base
  def balance
    total - (charge_payment + credit_payment)
  end
end
```

Comment: What if you did something where you were trying to find all where Order.balance was less than 0?

Comment: `Order.where(Order.balance < 0)`  Thats all I have :/

Comment: balance isn't a class method.

Comment: Arel, could you tell us more how `#total`, `#charge_payment` and `#credit_payment` work? Are they columns in `orders`? Do they refer a separate model like `OrderItem`? Multiple separate models?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's appropriate to suggest but I might suggest instead creating a column in your order table that reflects order status.  After each applied charge or credit you could just check the balance and then update the order status based on the balance?  That way you have a quick way to run a query to find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do addition and subtraction in SQL. Assuming `total`, `charge_payment`, and `credit_payment` are all integer columns on the orders table, then:

```
Order.where("(total - (charge_payment + credit_payment)) < 0")
```